# How do we take the integral of $\int3x^{-2}log_a^{2x}dx$?

Tags: calculus, analysis

$\int3x^{-2}\log_{a}^{2x}dx$ $\quad$   a>0

I solve this integration by parts. (not sure though) is there another way to solve this?
$ u=\log_{a}^{2x}, dv=3x^{-2}dx$

$ -\log_{a}^{2x}3x^{-1}+\int3x^{-2}\log_{a}^{e}dx$

$ -\log_{a}^{2x}3x^{-1}-\log_{a}^{e}3x^{-1}$

$ -3x^{-1}\log_{a}^{2xe}$

Comment: What is the argument of the log? Is this $\log_a 2x$?

Comment: @orion do u mean atthe last line? it is 2xe

Comment: @lyme No, he means every line which contains a logarithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integration by parts is by far the best way, it gets rid of the logarithm. I don't see any easier way.